# Rails ActiveRecord reference fetching in minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following Rails controller and view code:

discussion_thread_controller.rb

```
class DiscussionThreadsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_discussion_thread, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def show
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_discussion_thread
    @discussion_thread = DiscussionThread.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <%= @discussion_thread.author.name %><br>
    <small><strong>at: </strong><%= @discussion_thread.created_at.strftime('%d-%m-%Y, %H:%M %P')%></small>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body"><%= @discussion_thread.body %></div>
</div>
```

And this minitest

```
class DiscussionThreadsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @discussion_thread = discussion_threads(:one)
    @board = boards(:board_2)
    @user = users(:user_1)
  end

  test "should show discussion_thread" do
    get :show, params: {id: @discussion_thread.id}
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

When I access the controller from the browser, with say http://localhost:3000/discussion_threads/980190963, the page renders correctly.

For some reason the test is failing when trying to render @discussion_thread.author.name with

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

It appears, from going through the code in the debugger, that when the test runs the "author" method returns nil, while it returns the corresponding "User" object when accessing it from the browser. Also inspecting the @discussion_thread attributes shows valid "author_id".

Why is this happening?

My discussion_thread model look like this:

```
class DiscussionThread < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :author_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :board, class_name: 'Board', foreign_key: 'board_id'
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'author_id'

  has_many :replies, class_name: 'Post', foreign_key: 'thread_id', dependent: :destroy
end
```

and my test fixtures:

discussion_threads.yml

```
one:
  title: MyString
  body: MyText
  board: board_2
  author: user_1

two:
  title: MyString
  body: MyText
  board: board_2
  author: user_1
```

and users.yml

```
user_1:
  id: 1
  username: admin
  email_address: admin@xyz.com
  password_digest:...
  name: Mr. Foo
  is_admin: true
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ActiveRecord fixtures documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html):

> Fixtures that don't specify an ID get some extra features:
>
> - Stable, autogenerated IDs
> - Label references for associations (belongs_to, has_one, has_many)
> - HABTM associations as inline lists
>
> There are some more advanced features available even if the id is
>   specified:
>
> - Autofilled timestamp columns
> - Fixture label interpolation
> - Support for YAML defaults

Which is what caused the behavior reported above. Removing the id fields from fixtures fixed the problem, i.e. allowed the associations to work.

I wonder why these features are not available when one specifies the fixture record ID.